# Feature Request/Discussion - Markdown to write stylised LaTeX

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, stylised-latex

It could be interesting to get some markdown to write LaTeX as it is meant to be in any self-respecting LaTeX document (\latex)

[image: LaTeX]

What do you think?

Answer (score 6):

Personally I don't like this idea. The LaTeX logo looks great when it's font and style neatly matches the surrounding text. Which is nearly impossible to achieve on a web browser where you don't even know in advance which actual font will be used to render the page. The nice LaTeX logo sitting in the middle of a totally different font just screams "I'm out of place!" and breaks the flow of the text you're trying to read.

Comment: Right on.  This site should be promoting typographic excellence- having a PNG with the LaTeX logo jammed in to lines all over the place and completely out of flow with the surrounding text is not typographic excellence.

Comment: I wouldn't like the idea even if the style matched the surrounding text. Those logos might be ok in "marketing material", front covers of books, etc. However, in normal running text they are distracting and unnecessary; we do not try to reproduce the logos of any other products that we mention, either. The fact that something *can* be done does not always mean that it should be done...

Answer (score 1):

Others have written this in css. I'm aware of two implementations. This [one](http://edward.oconnor.cx/2007/08/tex-poshlet) and a later one based on it [here](https://cs.ucsd.edu/~scheckow/TeX.css) as used [here](https://cs.ucsd.edu/~scheckow/papers/tex2010.html).

It looks like a hassle to type by hand

```
<span class="tex">L<span class="raise">a</span>T<span class="drop">e</span>X</span>
```

but it appears to render appropriately in browsers that don't support css as LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

But wait; is [image: Latex] the name or the logo?  If it's the name, then the font is not part of the name and "LaTeX" should be rendered in the current font with the lowercase letters replaced by the raised/lowered smaller caps, an easy CSS job (maybe less so if you're really minding the kerning).  The result is IMHO no uglier than CamelCase.

(to be clear, I am voting for the feature, implemented in this fashion, not with an embedded png)